# Handling bad boolean data in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an MVP app that reads data from a SQL DB using EntityFramework. That data is copied from an external CMS website database, so the data isn't always reliable.

One of the fields I read is of 'bit' datatype in SQL, and is either a 1 or 0, and ASP.NET MVC wants it as a boolean, otherwise I get errors about converting boolean to int.

The problem is sometimes that bit value can be NULL in the DB, and that crashes my MVC app. I can't check for NULL, because I get errors that the boolean datatype can only be true or false.

#### Example

**Model**

```
namespace Foo.Models
{
    [Table("provider")]
    public class Bar
    {
        //can't check for null here, getter and setter only allow boolean
        public Boolean FooBar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
namespace Foo.Controllers
{
    public ActionResult BarList()
    {
         //Can't check for null here, because if(Boolean == null) will always evaluate to false
         List<Bar> bars = db.Bar.ToList();
         return View(bars);
    }
}
```

If FooBar is ever NULL, an error is thrown in the view that I can't have a NULL in a boolean. How do I handle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a generic [`Nullable<bool>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) (can also be expressed as `bool?`):

```
Nullable<bool> nullableBool;
```

Then use it as follows:

```
bool realBool = (nullableBool.HasValue && nullableBool);

// or

if (nullableBool == true) { ... } // true
else { ... } // false or null
```

Comment: @Dennis....I understand the part of !FooBar.HasValue() but not || FooBar.Value.  Could you explain?

Comment: Yes, this got me on the right track! This is what I really needed to get it fully working (I over-simplilfied my example).
  
    List<Bar> bars = db.Bar.Where(w => (w.FooBar.HasValue && (w.FooBar == true)).ToList()

Comment: compiler error: operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'bool?'

Answer (score 2):

You can make your boolean `NULLABLE`. It means that your bool can either have a value or not:

`public Boolean? FooBar { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can us `Nullable<T`>.  [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)

```
public Boolean? FooBar { get; set; }
```

> The two fundamental members of the Nullable structure are the
>   HasValue and Value properties. If the HasValue property for a
>   Nullable object is true, the value of the object can be accessed
>   with the Value property. If the HasValue property is false, the value
>   of the object is undefined and an attempt to access the Value property
>   throws an InvalidOperationException.